# Vue in laravel 5.8, populate table dynamically from axios response

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.8

I have a blade where I'm using a multiselect as dropdown, and when a selection is chosen it fires off an axios call which returns a json_encoded data set.

The blade is here:

```
<div class="uk-width-1-2">
    <multiselect
            label="name"
            track-by="value"
            v-model="CategoryValue"
            :options="CategoryOptions"
            :multiple="false"
            :taggable="true"
            @tag="getItems"
            @input="getItems"
            @search-change="val => read(val)"
            :preselect-first="false"
            :close-on-select="true" 
            :preserve-search="true" 
            placeholder="Choose Category..."
          ></multiselect>

    <div style="border:1px solid black; height:80%; margin-top:15px;">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Text</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody v-for="build in buildsList">
                <tr>
                    <td>@{{ build.build_code_formatted }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            
        </table>
    </div>
</div>


new Vue({

  data() {
    return{
       
        buildsList: {},
    }

  },
  methods: {
    
    getItems() {
      
      console.log(this.CategoryValue.value);

      axios.post('/getItems',{
            
        categoryCode: this.CategoryValue.value,

      })
      .then(function (response){
            
        this.buildsList = response.data;
            
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            
      });
    }
  }
})
```

And upon the callback I get a 200 and It does indeed log the buildsList so I know it is returning all of my data properly. However, when I get my data back in the console, it's not populating the html.

When I inspect the page elements there is no table body or data rows.

Also, my controller is returning this:

```
unction getItems(Request $request){

    return json_encode($this->itemService->getItems($request->Code));
}
```

and itemService is doing this:

```
$results = $pdoStatement->fetchAll();
    foreach ($results as &$r)
        $r = (object) $r;
    return $results;
```

So my data is coming back upon axios Call and it is formatted properly, but I just need to figure out why my table isn't dynamically populating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to change this part

```
this.buildsList = response.data;
```

to

```
.then((response) => {
    let data = response.data;

    for (let key in data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       this.$set(this.buildsList, key, data[key]);
     }
    }
})
```

Comment: That did not work, it says this.$set is not a function

Comment: Sorry I forgot about arrow function. Added fix please try again

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks that got the result, however, it only made one row instead of the 33 that I get back in my array. Is there a reason why it only displays one row?

Comment: I made fix in this row this.$set(this.buildsList, key, data[key]);
Please check my answer one more time